# Becoming a Dolby consultant

Tags: dolby

Hi,
I was wondering what does a Dolby consultant do and how can one become one?

What training and knowledge does it require? And where can i get it?

Will it be an added advantage or skill for 2 sound designer to get a job?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick search on the Internet and I found this from [Dolby's UK website](http://www.dolby.co.uk/about/who-we-are/our-history/history-4.html).

> Dolby's ultimate goal seemed simple
>   enough: to produce and profit from a
>   new range of theatre sound-processing
>   equipment. However, for that to
>   happen, film producers had to be
>   educated about the benefits of the new
>   format. Sound mixers had to be brought
>   up-to-date with new techniques.
>   Distributors had to be reassured that
>   stereo release prints were compatible
>   with mono theatres. Theatre equipment
>   suppliers had to be educated in system
>   requirements and installation
>   procedures. And theatre owners had to
>   be convinced that investing in the new
>   equipment would pay off at the box
>   office. As a result, it was necessary
>   to implement and staff a film sound
>   program that would reach out to all
>   these disparate segments of the film
>   industry.
>
> The resulting international program is
>   multifaceted. **Dolby film sound
>   consultants assist at the mix of films
>   slated for release with soundtracks
>   utilizing Dolby technology (available
>   today in every film production center
>   in the world).** Dolby has also
>   established offices in New York and
>   Los Angeles to further assist the US
>   film industry, and it regularly
>   conducts training courses for
>   equipment installers and technicians
>   on Dolby theatre sound equipment.

Also from [a BBC news article](http://www.bbc.co.uk/wiltshire/entertainment/films_and_tv/dolby.shtml):

> Staff at Wootton Bassett (Dolby Laboratories European Headquarters) are responsible for far more than the manufacture of the equipment – they also help “shape” film soundtracks. **Dolby’s “sound consultants” are responsible for helping film studios get the best out of the technology.** Dolby's 'consultants' travel internationally from Bollywood to Hollywood, ensuring that the soundtrack that gets shipped with the film meets their high standards.

As for training, I would try to do some networking with people who have already worked, or are currently working in that job. Again, my google search which took all of 10 seconds already provided a couple of contacts. I'm sure if you spend an hour or so, you could easily contact a host of people. If you send a polite email, people are usually very willing to offer advice. If you cannot find email addresses, try networking sites like LinkedIn.

Answer (score 1):

Check with mark and Alex at dreambasestudios.com
Both of them worked as Dolby consultants for a number of years until they decided to do their own stuff. You can actually read about them a designingsound.com (the logic article)

Tell them I said hi.

Erik @ Europa Sound